# How to download object from S3 with checksum validation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, download, multipart, checksum

I have a number of objects in an S3 bucket which I need to download to my local storage and validate the downloaded copy ideally using a checksum.
Is there a way of validating objects' integrity after downloading with the following assumptions:

- those objects have been delivered to my bucket by a third party and have the S3-native multipart checksum instead of MD5 in the metadata.
- I have no way to figure out what was the part size used for uploading those objects which I could use to calculate the mutipart checkum on the ground.
- I have no influence over that third party to privide either the md5 or the chunk size they used when they delivered the file to my bucket.

Any ideas?

Comment: You should trust TCP to do its job!

Comment: @jellycsc, I do have a reaonable level of trust in TCP but the customers may not... :)